# how to solve "Object of class Person could not be converted to string in error"

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Person {

  public $firstname = '';
  public $middlename = '';
  public $lastname = '';

  public function fullname($firstname, $middlename, $lastname){

     echo "my name is:".$firstname."".$middlename."".$lastname;

  }

}

$person = new Person;
$person->fullname('james', 'novlake', 'mendor');

echo $person;
?>
```

with the codes above, i get some error saying that object in class cannot converted in string, but somehow the $person is being echoed. i just want to get rid of the error in my browser hope someone can give me solution to this, thank you

Comment: why you echo the `$person;` ?

Comment: i just one to know if the function fullname is working hehe

Comment: Your function will work with: `$person->fullname('james', 'novlake', 'mendor');`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the object `$person`.

Actually you should return the data from function and since the returned data is string, you can print it using `echo` directly:

```
<?php
class Person {

  public $firstname = '';
  public $middlename = '';
  public $lastname = '';

  public function fullname($firstname, $middlename, $lastname){

     return "my name is:".$firstname."".$middlename."".$lastname;

  }

}

$person = new Person;
echo $person->fullname('james', 'novlake', 'mendor');
```

Please try to follow some best practices.

In your way, if you printing the string in the function itself, just

```
$person->fullname('james', 'novlake', 'mendor');
```

will do!

Comment: thanks mate i am new into php thats why i use echo for error handling which is seems wrong hehe

Answer (score 0):

You no need to echo the `$person` which is an object, your `$person->fullname(...)` did the thing you want.

From the function `fullname` you echo the `names`, so stop echoing the `object`.

```
class Person {
  public $firstname = '';
  public $middlename = '';
  public $lastname = '';

  public function fullname($firstname, $middlename, $lastname){
     echo "my name is:".$firstname."".$middlename."".$lastname;
  }
}

$person = new Person;
$person->fullname('james', 'novlake', 'mendor');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last statements

echo $person;

$person returns object so must be use print_r or you remove that line also.

```html
<?php
 class Person {
  
  public $firstname = '';
  public $middlename = '';
  public $lastname = '';
  
  public function fullname($firstname, $middlename, $lastname){
   
   echo "my name is:".$firstname."".$middlename."".$lastname;
   
  }
  
 }
 
 $person = new Person;
 $person->fullname('james', 'novlake', 'mendor');
?>
```

Or

```html
<?php
 class Person {
  
  public $firstname = '';
  public $middlename = '';
  public $lastname = '';
  
  public function fullname($firstname, $middlename, $lastname){
   
   return "my name is:".$firstname."".$middlename."".$lastname;
   
  }
  
 }
 
 $person = new Person;
 echo $person->fullname('james', 'novlake', 'mendor');
?>
```